# why does the sort(with key) function not work as intended?

Tags: python, list, sorting

```
# A function that returns the frequency of each value:
def myFunc(e):
     return cars.count(e)

cars = ['Ford', 'Ford', 'Ford', 'Mitsubishi','Mitsubishi', 'BMW', 'VW']

cars.sort(key=myFunc) 

print(cars)
```

Output:

```
['Ford', 'Ford', 'Ford', 'Mitsubishi', 'Mitsubishi', 'BMW', 'VW']
```

What I expect:

```
['BMW', 'VM', 'Mitsubishi', 'Mitsubishi', 'Ford', 'Ford', 'Ford']
```

Counts:

```
Ford - 3
Mitsubishi - 2
BMW - 1
VM - 1
```

It should sort in ascending order of count in the list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `cars` inside the key function, but `.sort` is in-place. This causes `cars` to be unreliable in intermediate calls to the key function.

We can see the problem if we print `cars` inside the key function:

```py
def myFunc(e):
    print(cars)
    return cars.count(e)


cars = ['Ford', 'Ford', 'Ford', 'Mitsubishi', 'Mitsubishi', 'BMW', 'VW']

cars.sort(key=myFunc)
```

This outputs

```
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
```

so `cars.count` will return `0` regardless what element is passed and the list will retain **its original order**.

Use `sorted(...)` which is not in-place:

```py
def myFunc(e):
    return cars.count(e)


cars = ['Ford', 'Ford', 'Ford', 'Mitsubishi', 'Mitsubishi', 'BMW', 'VW']

cars = sorted(cars, key=myFunc)

print(cars)
```

This outputs

```py
['BMW', 'VW', 'Mitsubishi', 'Mitsubishi', 'Ford', 'Ford', 'Ford']
```

As a side-note, in this case you can use `cars.count` directly, without defining the wrapper function:

```py
cars = sorted(cars, key=cars.count)
```

Comment: As a side-note, you don't need to redefine `myFunc`; you can call directly `cars = sorted(cars, cars.count)`

Comment: @Stef Indeed, I'll add a comment

Comment: @Stef You will need the keyword though - i.e., *cars = sorted(cars, key=cars.count)*

Comment: I'd remove the word "intermediate". That makes it sound like that myth that the key function is called for each comparison *during* the actual  sorting instead of just *before* the actual sorting starts.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is coming from the fact that you reference cars in the function while modifying it.

This doesn't happen if you get a copy:

```
def myFunc(e):
     return cars.count(e)

cars = ['Ford', 'Ford', 'Ford', 'Mitsubishi','Mitsubishi', 'BMW', 'VW']

cars2 = cars.copy()

cars2.sort(key=myFunc) 

print(cars2)
# ['BMW', 'VW', 'Mitsubishi', 'Mitsubishi', 'Ford', 'Ford', 'Ford']
```

That said, this approach is not efficient as you need to read again the whole list for each element.

use a counter instead:

```
from collections import Counter

cars = ['Ford', 'Ford', 'Ford', 'Mitsubishi','Mitsubishi', 'BMW', 'VW']
c = Counter(cars)

cars.sort(key=c.get)

print(cars)
# ['BMW', 'VW', 'Mitsubishi', 'Mitsubishi', 'Ford', 'Ford', 'Ford']
```